# Flutter : How to setState variable comes as arguments

Tags: flutter, dart, arguments, setstate

I have this page which receive an argument variable (weekId) from previous page ,i want to change this value after press on button Icon to increase or decrease it.
I did it but when the page rebuild it take the received argument variable value again.
How can i fix it :

```
class PreDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PreDetailState createState() => _PreDetailState();
}

class _PreDetailState extends State<PreDetail> {
  var weekId;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List preData = [];
    Map rdata = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    var userName = rdata['username'];
    var weekId = rdata['week_id'];

//ok
    var mywidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    Future<List> get_week_pre() async {
      print('weekId = $weekId'); -----------// variable I want to setState
      try {
        //ok
        var url =
            'https://technosat-iq.com/myexpect/api/controller/matchs/pre_week.php?username=$userName&week_id=$weekId';
        var response = await http.get(url);
        var data = await jsonDecode(response.body);
        print(data);
        for (var x in data) {
          WeekPre preList = WeekPre(
              x['username'],
          preData.add(preList);
        }
        return preData;
      } catch (Expection) {
        print(Expection);
      }
    }

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: get_week_pre(),
      builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none ||
            snapshot.data == null) {
          return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(strokeWidth: 6.0),
          );
        } else {
          return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text('Points Detail'),
                centerTitle: true,
                backgroundColor: Colors.orange[800],
              ),
              body: Container(
                child: ListView(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          height: 50,
                          width: 0.2 * mywidth,
                          child: IconButton(
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.arrow_right,
                                size: 50,
                                color: Colors.pink[800],
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                weekId = int.parse(weekId);
                                setState(() {
                                  weekId++; -------------// here I want to setState
                                });
                                print(weekId);
                              }),
                        ),],)],),));}},);}}
```

can receive the arguments outside the build context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 problems:

- you initiate weekId inside build method. Fix : Add initState then initiate weekId in there. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html
- you do not set the state variable, instead you create a new local variable weekId inside the build method. Fix: remove var keyword before weekId in the method.

  ```
  @override
  void initState(){
      super.initState();


      SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((Duration _) async {
        Map rdata = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
        var userName = rdata['username'];
        weekId = rdata['week_id'];
        setState((){});
         });
      }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { ... }
  ```

But there is a simpler way. The choice is up to you:

```
class PreDetail  extends StatefulWidget {
  final String weekId;
  @override
  _PreDetail State 

  const PreDetail({Key key, @required this.weekId}) : super(key: key);createState() => _PreDetail State();
}

class _PreDetail State extends State<PreDetail > {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      widget.weekId,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir, the problem is i receive arguments inside build context and the initial state outside, how can i did that

Comment: i did that ,but i get error :The following assertion was thrown building Builder:
dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_ModalScopeStatus>() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called
before _PreDetailState.initState() completed.
When an inherited widget changes, for example if the value of Theme.of() changes, its dependent